# What are some services that provide user authentication for your website?

Tags: openid, facebook-authentication, authentication, oauth-provider

I am developing a small website and I don't want to implement a full authentication workflow given the scope of the project and I can't rely that all users have Facebook account (so I need fallback from Facebook Connect). I want to offload the user authetication management task to a 3rd party service and I recently came across [Mozilla Persona](https://persona.org/) which seems exactly what I am looking for. However, its still in early stage it seems - what are some other services that do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an exhaustive list of services in [passport's strategy section](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport#strategies-1). I still have to research which one I like the most.

Comment: Found an [out of box solution](https://www.dailycred.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Janrain](http://developers.janrain.com/) to allow users to choose from multiple authentication sources (Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc.)  This is probably the most popular library out there for that sort of thing at this time.  Uh, or at least it seemed like it was when I had to do something like this a while back.